# Adding multiple images from a list in Tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a few images that I would like to display. I have tried storing the labels in a list, however when I call pack() only the last png shows like so:

[image]

How can I make them all appear?

```
import os

icons = []
for f in os.listdir():
    if f.endswith('.png'):
        print(f)
        img = Image.open(f)
        resized = img.resize((16, 16), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        new_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized)
        label_img = tk.Label(root, image=new_img)
        icons.append(label_img)
        label_img.pack()
```

Comment: You need to save references to the images (`new_img`) to prevent them from being garbage-collected.  Saving the Labels themselves is not necessary (unless you plan on doing something further with them, of course).

Comment: Cheers! So if anyone ever wondering, just append the the `new_img` in `icons`. Then seperate loop over icons creating the tk Label object and calling `pack()` on each label